# Holomorphic functions that maps an arc into the unit circle

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

Let $f$ be a holomorphic function defined on an open domain containing an arc $\gamma$ of the unit circle, which maps $\gamma$ into the unit circle. What can be said about $f$? More precisely, is there an analog (for general $\gamma$ ) of the blaschke-factor-product criterion of the special case where $\gamma$ is the unit circle itself?

This problem occurred to me when I was thinking about the structure of the set of polynomials that maps the unit circle to a fixed nonempty subset of $\mathbb{C}$. The precise statement of the problem I was thinking about is the following:

> Let $T \subset \mathbb{C}$ be a nonempty subset of $\mathbb{C}$. Is it true that there is a $p(x) \in \mathbb{C}[x]$, such that any $f \in \mathbb{C}[x]$ satisfying $f( \{z \in \mathbb{C} : |z| = 1 \} ) = T$ is of the form $p(cx^d)$ for some unitary $c \in \mathbb{C}$ and $d \in \mathbb{Z}_{>0}$?

One may see that if one has a nice description of holomorphic functions that maps a general arc into the unit circle, then at least the structure of the set of polynomials that maps the unit circle to a fixed nonempty subset of $\mathbb{C}$ would be clear.

Comment: take any singular inner function where the support of its associated singular measure (on the unit circle) is not the full circle (eg $f(z)=e^{\frac{z+1}{z-1}}, z \ne 1$) then $f$ extends analytically on the complement of the support of its singular measure and maps it into the unit circle so there is no easy answer at least as the way the problem is formulated now